# The Text to Speech API for my HTML/JS chatbot is not inputting spoken words into the proper text field

Tags: html, windows, speech-to-text

I'm trying to make an HTML site that has a simple chatbot functionality, but some of the speech to text parts aren't working.

The chatbot should listen for a keyword, then begin to populate the input text field with what was spoken afterwards, and then send the message after around 2.5 seconds of silence. However, the speech recognition is not putting anything in the element, and there are no errors, so I can't tell what or where the problem is.

```js
let voices = [];
//get voices
};

let mode = "basic";

const messages = document.getElementById('messages');
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');
const startListeningButton = document.getElementById('startListeningButton');

const botResponses = [
  //fallback bot responses
];

const customResponses = {
  //bot responses
};

// Initialize SpeechRecognition
const recognition = new(window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition)();
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';

// indicate if listening
let isListening = false;

startListeningButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!isListening) {
    recognition.start();
    startListeningButton.textContent = "Stop Listening";
  } else {
    recognition.stop();
    startListeningButton.textContent = "Start Listening";
  }
  isListening = !isListening;
});

// Listen for spoken words
recognition.onstart = function() {
  console.log('Listening...');
  isListening = true;
};

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript.trim().toLowerCase();
  console.log('Heard:', transcript);

  if (transcript.includes("red")) {
    // Check if the keyword "red" is detected
    const startIndex = transcript.indexOf("red") + 3;
    const recognizedSpeech = transcript.substring(startIndex).trim();
    input.value = recognizedSpeech;
  }
};

recognition.onend = function() {
  console.log('Stopped listening...');
};

function generateResponse(message) {
  message = message.toLowerCase().trim();

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(customResponses)) {
    const regex = new RegExp(key, 'gi');

    if (regex.test(message)) {
      const responses = value;
      const response = getResponse(responses);
      speak(response);
      return response;
    }
  }

  const response = getRandomBotResponse();
  speak(response);
  return response;
}

function getResponse(responses) {
  if (Array.isArray(responses)) {
    return responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
  } else {
    return responses;
  }
}

function getRandomBotResponse() {
  return botResponses[Math.floor(Math.random() * botResponses.length)];
}

function speak(message) {
  const speechSynthesisUtterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(message);
  const ziraVoice = voices.find(voice => voice.name === 'Microsoft Zira - English (United States)');

  if (ziraVoice) {
    speechSynthesisUtterance.voice = ziraVoice;
  } else {
    console.warn('Microsoft Zira voice not found. Using default voice.');
  }

  speechSynthesis.speak(speechSynthesisUtterance);
}

function sendMessage() {
  const message = input.value.trim();
  if (!message) {
    return;
  }

  const messageElement = document.createElement("div");
  messageElement.classList.add("message", "user-message");
  messageElement.innerHTML = `<div>${message}</div>`;
  messages.appendChild(messageElement);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const botMessage = generateResponse(message);
    const botMessageElement = document.createElement("div");
    botMessageElement.classList.add("message", "bot-message", mode);
    botMessageElement.innerHTML = `<div>${botMessage}</div>`;
    messages.appendChild(botMessageElement);
  }, 1000); // Delay bot response by 1 second

  input.value = "";
}

input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    sendMessage();
  }
});

sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sendMessage();
});
```

```html
<div id="chatbot">
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter Message Here!"> 
  <button id="sendButton">Send</button>
  <button id="startListeningButton">Start Listening</button>
</div>
```

(I know a lot of that is unnecessary, but since I have no idea what the problem is, I thought it best to show it too)

Comment: What's going on with the `};` on the third line of the javascript?

Comment: Here is the full section of that part:                                                                              let voices = [];
        window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function () {
            voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
            console.log(voices);
        };

Comment: Please edit your question to make it a [mcve]. It's hard to help when it's incomplete and contains syntax errors.